# AS3IsoLib Sprite SVG

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to add a sprite to my grid and doing such with a PNG works fine but doing so with an SVG doesn't yield the same result. Is it possible to use an SVG image as a sprite and add it to my as3isolib grid?

```
myLoader = new Loader();

myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, OnComplete);
myLoader.load(new URLRequest('x.svg'));

function OnComplete():void
{
    player = new IsoSprite();
    player.moveTo(14, 15, 0);
    player.setSize(50, 50, 1);
    player.sprites = [myLoader];
    scene.addChild(player);
    scene.render();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SVG is not an image as is, it's a XML-type file, so you need to parse it somehow prior to displaying. Say, use this https://github.com/LucasLorentz/AS3SVGRenderer library. There are some more, I've posted the first one found.